# can't pass "this" as parameter in spookyjs emit

Tags: node.js, events, phantomjs, casperjs, spookyjs

I'm trying to pass "this" as an argument to Spooky.emit, but I get no output.
This is my code:

```
var Spooky = require('spooky');

var spooky = new Spooky({
    child: {
        transport: 'http'
    },
    casper: {
        logLevel: 'debug',
        verbose: true
    }
}, function() {

    spooky.start(
        'http://google.com');
    spooky.then(function() {
        this.emit('msg', this);
    });
    spooky.run();
});

spooky.on('msg', function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
});
```

Someone knows what could be wrong here?

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo. I got no output at all.

Comment: you want to pass the spooky instance with your emit, is this correct?

Comment: Is any way to do it?